# Is a method always async if it has the key word "async" and "await"?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Many blogs introduce the "**async**" & "**await**", they usually use some demo code like this ：

```
public async Task Go()
{
    var t = await GetNameAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}

public async Task<string> GetNameAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    return "Jim";
}
```

I am very confused about this, like the above methods, once run into the method ,it will be blocked as they get the **await** in the first line. I think they are sync methods here, even it as async & await.

I am confused are these method Async?

As my understanding, the async method should like as following,it will get a task, but it not run it immediately, it should do some sync things, and then await the task.

```
public async Task<string> GetNameAsync()
{
    var t = Task.Delay(10000);
    //1.do some thing
    //2.do some thing
    await t;

    return "Jim";
}
```

The async and sync differences between, async  isn't always more quickly than sync.
async:

```
public async Task<string> GetNameAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    return "Jim";
}
```

sync:

```
public string GetNameAsync()
{
    Task.Delay(10000);
    return "Jim";
}
```

Comment: What difference does it make whether or not it does anything between starting the task and waiting for it to finish? Why should a method suddenly be no longer async if those 2 things were done prior to starting the task?

Comment: It means that the asynchronous method will not necessarily block the execution of the whole program / thread. While *await*ing, it indicates to the runtime that the current thread could "pause" here, and perform other task (for instance, treat a request in ASP.NET, do another work queued for a parallel task, or render UI / treat other UI even. This is especially important for UI, since there is only one UI thread for the whole .NET application.

Comment: Without async / await for a long job, the UI would basically "freeze" at your code, during the waiting time, because the thread yould not be used to paint and handle mouse moves and clicks, window moves etc... , for instance

Comment: `async` just changes what you're allowed to write inside the method. `await` is a way of indicating "the current method cannot make any further progress until `x` is finished", when `x` is whatever `Task`/awaitable you've passed to `await`. Indicating that the thread currently running this method can go off and be made use of elsewhere until that `x` has finished.

Comment: The point of `await` is that your "do some thing" lines can be done elsewhere entirely - `await` returns immediately so the thread can be freed up and the rest of the method is effectively wired up as a continuation to be run when the asynchronous operation is complete.

Comment: @AntP, when method A is waiting for "await"，A is blocked.  am I right?

Comment: @AdvancingEnemy `A` is "blocked" in the sense that it doesn't continue until the operation is complete, but its execution context (i.e. the thread it is executing on) isn't. That's what the benefit of async is. It's not there to stop the method being blocked because that is self-evidently impossible (I can't carry on working with resource x until I have finished retrieving resource x).

Comment: @AdvancingEnemy "Methods" cannot be blocked. Threads that execute them are.

Comment: thanks all friends. @AntP, so, the sync method won't block the thread. But a  async method isn't always more quickly than sync. Both of them need to wait for 1s  delay time, like I edit in the last. Am I right?

Comment: When did execution time become part of the discussion?

Comment: @AdvancingEnemy exactly - but async isn't about making operations faster, it's about being able to run operations concurrently. In this case that's achieved by freeing the thread up to do other things while this method waits.